# How to deal with duplicate mulitiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

say I have a dataframe with two indices : name and date

It looks like:

```
                  col1  col2
name   date
a   2018-03-30     :      :
    2018-06-30     :      :
    2018-06-30     :      :
    2018-12-30     :      :
b   2017-01-31     :      :
    2018-06-30     :      :
:       :          :      :
:       :          :      :
```

I found that there are two "2018-06-30" in a. How can I correct the second one to "2018-09-30"?

Comment: But if you correct the second one to `2018-09-30` you would have two `2018-09-30`?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake. I edited it.

Comment: I am cleaning a data from a csv so there are no codes about the data.  what I did was just set the date to datetime and have name and date become indices

Comment: The python libary pandas could help.

Comment: How do you plan to clean the data? Only keep the first occurrence?